# How to "render" \b in a string in python

Tags: python, string, escaping

I have a string with "\b" characters.
Is there a way to "render" the string or "apply" the escape sequences, in order to make the string looking it looks with the print() function?

How it looks like: `Test..\b\b! 12344\b5`

How it should look like: `Test! 12345`

Do you have an idea to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes. Printing does exactly what I'm looking for, but I need it in a variable.

Comment: `new_string = old_string.replace('.\b','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with regex.

```
import re

def b(a):
  while '\b' in a:
    a = re.sub('[^\b]\b', '', a)
  return a

b('Test..\b\b! 12344\b5')
# Out: 'Test! 12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be simply to use the replace method of the string object:

```
st = 'Test.\b!'
st.replace('.\b','') 
# Out: 'Test!'
```

Comment: This was just an example. In the real string I don't know which characters are in front of the \b